# Does AWS sam cli print template.yaml config file with all variables resolved

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, variables, aws-lambda, sam

I have switched from serverless to sam cli. One useful function serverless had was [serverless print](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/print) which allowed you to print the output of your yaml file with all the local variables resolved. This was a useful tool for checking if your syntax is correct or if the variables are resolving as you expect.

Is that any way to do this with AWS sam cli?

e.g.

`sam print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Outputs` section of SAM template. 
You can check the [AWS SAM template anatomy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy.html) to understand better.

> **Outputs (optional)**
>
> The values that are returned whenever you view your stack's properties. For example, you can declare an output for an S3 bucket
> name, and then call the aws cloudformation describe-stacks AWS Command
> Line Interface (AWS CLI) command to view the name. This section corresponds directly with the Outputs section of AWS CloudFormation templates.

You will need to make use of [Intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) within your `Outputs` section to print out the final resolved value at runtime.

```yml
Outputs:
  BackupLoadBalancerDNSName:
    Description: The DNSName of the backup load balancer
    Value: !GetAtt BackupLoadBalancer.DNSName
    Condition: CreateProdResources
  InstanceID:
    Description: The Instance ID
    Value: !Ref EC2Instance
```

*If you just wish to validate if your `SAM` is correct or not you could use the following command:*

```sh
$ sam validate
```

###### Posting the answer here so that it may help others in future!